# Why can my class inherit from itself using different generic arguments?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I am currently looking at a class that is created this way:

```
public class MyClass<T> : MyClass<T, OtherInfo>
```

`OtherInfo` is an existing type.

To me, it looks like this class is inheriting from itself. Is this true?

Comment: just this part:

    public class PluginLoader<TInstrument> : PluginLoader<IInstrumentPlugin<TInstrument>, TInstrument, InstrumentPluginMetadata, InstrumentInfo>

@Ramza, can you explain more? If I ctrl click on the (what I thought was) base class, there is no base class of this type.

Comment: Where is the definition for the PluginLoader class that has multiple generic arguments? Hint: https://dotnetfiddle.net/owsd9K

Comment: No, it's not true. `MyClass<T>` and `MyClass<T, OtherInfo>` are distinct types -- they have to be, since they have different generic parameter lists. That both classes are named `MyClass` isn't relevant in this case; to the runtime, these classes are actually named ``MyClass`1`` and ``MyClass`2``, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write methods in the same class that have the same name, but you have to make sure that they have different parameters. For example, this is valid:

```
void Foo() {}
void Foo(string p1) {}
void Foo(int p2) {}
void Foo(string p1, int p2) {}
```

This means to correctly identity which method to execute you need to know *both* the name and its parameters.

You can do the same thing with types. You can have multiple types with the same name, but different *generic arguments*. This is also valid:

```
public class MyClass : MyClass<int> {}
public class MyClass<T1> : MyClass<int, int> {}
public class MyClass<T1, T2> {}
```

Just like with methods, to identify which class you're referring to you need *both* its name and generic arguments.

In your case, `MyClass<X>` is a different class than `MyClass<X,Y>` - they are defined independently in your source code (or referencing library). So no, it's not inheriting from itself.

Comment: It's important to note that while method overloading and identically named types with different generic parameter lists are somewhat analogous, the mechanisms are very different -- there is no equivalent to overload resolution for generic types and the types have different names at runtime (whereas the methods are really all named `Foo`).